# Directive rendering delay when using angularjs and requirejs

Tags: angularjs, requirejs

Basically, my problem is that "I am {{ 10 + 13 }}" is what is being rendered for a second/half a second, before the "store" module is being created in main.js.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="store">
    <head>
        <title>...</title>
        <script data-main="main.js" src="../bower_components/requirejs/require.js"></script>
        <link href="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    I am {{ 10 + 13 }}
</body>
```

main.js sets the requirejs configs, requires the angular library and sets the "store" module:

```
require.config({
    paths: {angular: '../bower_components/angular/angular.min'},
    shim: {angular: {exports: 'angular'}}
});

require(['angular'], function(angular) {
    var app = angular.module('store', []);
});
```

I think the reason this occurs, is because main.js and the angular library are being loaded asynchronously by requirejs (with an "async" attribute on the script tag), so the DOM gets rendered before the store module has been created, thus creating a delay.

What would I have to do to avoid this gap that occurs between rendering "I am {{ 10 + 13 }}" and "I am 13"? I could load both main.js and the angular js synchronous/without requirejs, but that does not seem like a best practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @K.Toress mentioned, the way to fix this problem would be to use [`ng-cloak`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak) on the body element or more specifically on the problematic elements to improve the rendering of the page.

Some css/style is needed to put the ng-cloak elements in `display: none;`, so if you are using angular in CSP mode, you will have no problem, because the angular-csp.css stylesheet would normally be included. However, if you are not using angular in CSP mode, the css rule embedded within angular.js/angular.min.js would not have any effect, since the library will most likely be loaded after the DOM is completely loaded. For this reason, you need to manually add some style for the `[ng-cloak]`elements:

```
<head>
    ...
    <style>[ng-cloak] {display: none;}</style>
</head>
```

For your information, since angular can be loaded after the DOM or before the code base, you should not include an `ng-app` attribute to the document, but rather bootstrap angular manually to avoid any asynchronous issues:

```
require(['angular'], function(angular) {
    var app = angular.module('app', []);
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use [`ng-cloack`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak) directive

```
<body>
    I am <span ng-cloak>{{ 10 + 13 }}</span>
</body>
```

add css

```
[ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], [data-ng-cloak], [x-ng-cloak], .ng-cloak, .x-ng-cloak {
    display: none !important;
}
```

didn't test you can give a try. :)

[Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/29pvwzQOhTg8sqFkrPUs?p=preview)

**UPDATE**

hide the `<body>` until `angular` available.

```
.initial-hide {
   display: none;
}

.show {
    display: block !important;
}


<body class="initial-hide" ng-class="{show : initedScripts}">
    ......
    ......
</body>
```

body will get `initial-hide` and gets hide until `show` class applied to it. `show` class applied when variable `initedScripts` sets to `true`.

in the **JS**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.run(function($rootScope) {
     $rootScope.initedScripts = true;
});

set `initedScripts` to `true` in the run block and that means angular loaded successfully.
```

here is a [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/FXQxrL1aQIXcXXzxal25?p=preview)

*i added a 2 seconds timeout to delay the invoking of angularjs by requirJs*

Comment: This does not seem to work unless I manually link the angular-csp.css stylesheet. I don't think I wish to do that, since I am not in CSP mode. Isn't the ng-cloack directive suppose to work even in non-CSP mode?

Comment: It says that in non-CSP mode, the css rules are embedded within angular.js and angular.min.js...so I don't understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: Ah, but the library is loaded after the DOM has been loaded, so I have exactly the same problem than before.

Comment: I updated the answer may be it will solve your problem. :) please check.

Comment: hey thanks for the help!! i think I found a better solution if you look at my answer below. angular automatically removes the `ng-cloak` attribute when compiling the template, so no need for an extra class. thumbs up!

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your expressions to be interpolated in some custom tags that are supported by angular. Thus they won't be rendered by browser before angular is loaded and compiles all stuff on your page.

Which one to choose depends on your real markup.
You can even wrap this in a custom directive

Comment: I think I would still have the same problem as it would not prevent the Angular html template from being briefly displayed by the browser in its raw (uncompiled) form while the application is loading